# Vega Wordcloud Faceting

Tags: google-colaboratory, facet, vega, word-cloud, trellis

i really like the look of the vega Word Clouds:
https://vega.github.io/vega/examples/word-cloud/

I'm currently using the spec from the link as follows in colab:

```
spec = "insert spec here"

#Option one:
from altair import vega
vega.renderers.enable('colab')
vega.Vega(spec)

#Option two:
import panel as pn
from vega import Vega
pn.extension('vega')
pn.pane.Vega(spec)
```

But actually i want to make faceted wordclouds with vega. I currently load my data as json from my github account which is also slightly annoying, but i found no way to reference python variables in the vega spec.
Does anyone maybe have a hint, how i could layout the vega wordcloud in a grid by groups specified in my data? My json has this structure: [{"text":text,"group":group}], drawing the wordclouds from this works, but not the faceting by the group field. I know vega-lite can do faceting, but it can't draw the beautiful wordcloud it seems.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working example of Vega spec using *facet* with your data.

For illustration only, the formula field for *angle* places words with larger field *size* in horizontal position.

[View in Vega online editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykSArJQBWENgDsQAGhAATONABONHJnaT0AQQAEAdzaLZ2qABs2DI8RoQGSEzQBeSNRO3ycNKGvFltANT5tRQU4JEVYbRwkHDhFbSQmCExFJC8ISmkQNUwTODQQHQB1A1lTc1lM3RpZejQAFgAGBpl4GjIseqaZKNlZGh80AEZmkCZUgGsyRXNxCvR2tiTdGDo8mRMkAE9zTDRQJhnZCHyAMxMGCBhMqDZzhHFj1AAmbqRe-rIhhoBfGVlnFCoADaoHESAQeXQmASuUyDEUJnyWFw+CIKV01DojCYF1iN3EmDgBMoNwQBHEmyQ4gAHhxSBQAPonVJwTAM-SGMoWAjIfqcHD2TAiMSSGTJKkQE4GBBoEFZTYxU7ShgbTJIR4gKlkWEyODUnCKfL-TAMBCUCCOODaAB8AF5tABmbQAfm0DW0qG0QIAtHUBFJvQ7mtpvYN-W6pNow5Gg5G-QBdIFnNgGAAUKVmbAQqYAlNoAFTaADsOfjIG+8YrMmgdgUstB4MhIBuZkNYoVTZK-TsmVkWaQ-T2cgB+WhTB1IBONDgJjmWT1bIgAro5ZkGbIkKBIAAxLIBEgAJxPAAcmW3ADYBE8oAeGmeDw6DwID0WQJX4zJkIpxo85ZgO-kUzmDgmQnNMMqoKAzJQKyQ5ghCpwsrsfwjlCMJrCAQEMDgTCbIB0zYeWvxZHQsKQfO1K7ORFpkGCiLoFEwTElhIHEWBjb4cBq4gESNzyEO2HGpCoBVDUVzUW0dH5KJtTEa07RUaANFSeg8kdN8GmfmEP71vKiroMEXiZLxbD8eRRKEoa5HUkOxB2AwkI-DIMniUpkk9ugLncXh5F2ecjlyXAbQdBJtEeRgQUKdxU4mPRoB+Q5+RMJFeQaZpoD-vpFHIZO4FDsagKTkh3EmWZoAWbEQ6EpRQ5TjOc7VYuy67MRdiSbZ9lNjBBKVcRYwQDO-TCSACVNnYOAwAkrKeNFNCxUONZkc2twGKB06zqOC4MkugpETIgnOMNMUmAA8lEUB0D58WdUMmkYGwpBWVBc2nedl0df5aANJQAhpWKGaStKumZU2HKlGYFiZBaDjDcp4VAi5kZqZgZbEY1tXrQ1W07SuxHTNChIY-VRrOKalBarCbESFRIAABIzqQahQEg2gAHJwA5kaaMoPYyFKBIAMqWkTG3oMaZPQ6lfPU0LMMAEpapugwvCeH4gD0fQDM8FY65WQA)
[image]

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega/v5.json",
  "description": "A word cloud visualization depicting Vega research paper abstracts.",
  "title": "A Wordcloud",
  "width": 400,
  "height": 400,
  "padding": 10,
  "background": "ghostwhite",

  "layout": {
    "bounds": "flush",
    "columns": 2,
    "padding": 10
  },

  "data": [
    {
      "name": "table",
      "url": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nyanxo/vega_facet_wordcloud/main/split.json",
  
      "transform": [
        {
          "type": "formula", 
          "as": "angle",
          "expr": "datum.size >= 3 ? 0 : [-45,-30, -15, 0, 15, 30, 45][floor(random() * 7)]"
          }
        ]
    }
  ],
  "scales": [
    {
      "name": "color",
      "type": "ordinal",
      "domain": {"data": "table", "field": "text_split"},
      "range": ["#d5a928", "#652c90", "#939597"]
    }
  ],

  "marks": [
   {
      "type": "group",
      "from": {
        "facet": {
          "name": "facet",
          "data": "table",
          "groupby": "group"
        }
      },

      "title": {
        "text": {"signal": "parent.group"},
        "frame": "group"
      },

      "encode": {
        "update": {
          "width": {"signal": "width"},
          "height": {"signal": "height"}
        }
      },

"marks": [
    {
      "type": "rect",
      "encode": {
        "enter": {
          "x": {"value": 0},
          "width": {"signal": "width" },
          "y": {"value": 0},
          "height": {"signal": "height"},
          "fill": {"value": "beige"}
        }
      }
    },

    {
      "type": "text",
      "from": {"data": "facet"},
      "encode": {
        "enter": {
          "text": {"field": "text_split"},
          "align": {"value": "center"},
          "baseline": {"value": "alphabetic"},
          "fill": {"scale": "color", "field": "text_split"}
        },
        "update": {"fillOpacity": {"value": 1}},
        "hover": {"fillOpacity": {"value": 0.5}}
      },
      "transform": [
        {
          "type": "wordcloud",
          "size": {"signal": "[width, height]"},
          "text": {"field": "text_split"},
          "rotate":  {"field": "datum.angle"},
          "font": "Helvetica Neue, Arial",
          "fontSize": {"field": "datum.size"},
          "fontSizeRange": [12, 28],
          "padding": 2
        }
      ]
    }
    ]
   }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't facet a word cloud as it requires a CountPattern transform which will destroy any faceting field you try to use. Instead you will need to provide a separate data object for each word cloud you want and then concatenate them together.

Edit

[Link](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykSArJQBWENgDsQAGhAATONABONHJnaT0AQQAEAdzaLZ2qABs2DI8RoQGSEzQBeSNRO3ycNKGvFltANT5tRQU4JEVYbRwkHDhFbSQmCExFJC8ISmkQNUwTODQQHQB1A1lTc1lM3RpZejQAFgAmAAYZeBoyLHqmlpAo2VkaHzQe2WcUVABtUHEkBDz0TATczIZFE3ysXHwiFN1qOkYmBghYqAlMOHFMSjOEAnEATyRxAA8OUgoAfQAzVLhMT76QxlCwEZCDTg4ezXUQSEAAXwAujJoHYFGgpiAZnN8mczIpMpgHjF8iVBnZMrI2OCNKBRot8osmMsZN8aHATBUFnAXgCIFC6AiZCkfPMJiAAMSyARIACcDQAHJkJQA2AQNKCyprK2UAZllAllAHYQIikTITEgHuZMGhQH0BkNUM0ZHiGAhxBA0A0ZExzOJZF70N8GCZ1jI7O0NCA7Ot4TJkIoANZBzHY+YgKAc8NZYkZsiKcw4TJJB7LdBZsOZb6FhB2kC-LO21DTWYZxv-SljRlLPIyAtFpgPDEgAcMYtm+MgS5neT18f0+agKo1GD1iBRinoOrdIUYODtTotkAbsgzdbb3fw68JsIpjGgIkk7m86u1+v08YNv62qczthzselwXASx4XK+x5shyXJZDyfICr+Eb2Ge9bEHYDAZlmVyxHuTBICc9jiEuIBoSYGH5HYOAwAk-yeHubJVseqLlpmbD4tW7KcoycGfPy0IIlOC7OMRDEmAA8lEUB0MOx6keRqAAIw3hgbCkKBoCiRJqTSah6HzE0lACNeU7JM8EDfAYdaTI+eb5ECpRmBYJaOGKO4tG5yKwRBGmcTB4HwfxU4WVc+QABIcqQahQEg2gAHJwBhUjaJoygUqy5wAMouQASs8ZBigpPoCCqnkOoMZDekiVVmkAA)

[image]

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega/v5.json",
  "description": "A word cloud visualization depicting Vega research paper abstracts.",
  "title": "A Wordcloud",
  "width": 420,
  "height": 400,
  "padding": 0,
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "table",
      "url": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nyanxo/vega_facet_wordcloud/main/split.json"
    }
  ],
  "scales": [
    {
      "name": "color",
      "type": "ordinal",
      "domain": {"data": "table", "field": "text_split"},
      "range": ["#d5a928", "#652c90", "#939597"]
    }
  ],
  "layout": {"padding": 20, "columns": 2, "bounds": "full", "align": "all"},
  "marks": [
    {
      "name": "cell",
      "type": "group",
      "style": "cell",
      "from": {
        "facet": {"name": "facet", "data": "table", "groupby": ["group"]}
      },
      "encode": {
        "update": {"width": {"signal": "400"}, "height": {"signal": "400"}}
      },
      "marks": [
        {
          "type": "text",
          "from": {"data": "facet"},
          "encode": {
            "enter": {
              "text": {"field": "text_split"},
              "align": {"value": "center"},
              "baseline": {"value": "alphabetic"},
              "fill": {"scale": "color", "field": "text_split"}
            },
            "update": {"fillOpacity": {"value": 1}},
            "hover": {"fillOpacity": {"value": 0.5}}
          },
          "transform": [
            {
              "type": "wordcloud",
              "size": [400, 400],
              "text": {"field": "text_split"},
              "font": "Helvetica Neue, Arial",
              "fontSizeRange": [12, 56],
              "padding": 2
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. So would it be possible to facet if i computed the wordcounts beforehand?

Comment: Yes, that would be possible. Don't forget to mark as solved if your problem is solved.

Comment: I computed the word counts per group now, i'm stuck with the faceting though and also had to removed the transform which also computes the rotation of words: https://vega.github.io/editor/#/gist/de224a20126569d8f0df402e47ff5cdb/spec.json